# How can we add Admob and Firebase crashlytics to Android studio bumble bee Build.Gradle file

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, admob, crashlytics

How can we add Admob and Firebase crashlytics  to Android studio bumble bee

earlier the build.gradle: was some thing like this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"
        // Add the following line:
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'  // Google Services plugin
        // Add the Crashlytics Gradle plugin
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

However now the changes look like these

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false

    

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I tried adding these lines

```
// Add the following line:
        id 'com.google.gms:google-services' version '4.3.10' apply false
        // Google Services plugin
        // Add the Crashlytics Gradle plugin
        id 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle' version '2.8.1' apply false
```

But it  error is

```
Caused by: org.gradle.plugin.internal.InvalidPluginIdException: plugin id 'com.google.gms:google-services' is invalid: Plugin id contains invalid char ':' (only ASCII alphanumeric characters, '.', '_' and '-' characters are valid)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginId.validate(DefaultPluginId.java:65)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginId.of(DefaultPluginId.java:48)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.PluginRequestCollector$PluginDependencySpecImpl.<init>(PluginRequestCollector.java:139)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.PluginRequestCollector$PluginDependencySpecImpl.<init>(PluginRequestCollector.java:129)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.PluginRequestCollector$PluginDependenciesSpecImpl.id(PluginRequestCollector.java:116)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `buildscript`  above `plugins`

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    // Add our classpath 
     classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
     classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1' 
 }
}
 plugins {
      id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0' apply false
      id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.0' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: this approach will interfere with many features like binding...

Answer (score 17):

Add `com.google.gms.google-services` and `com.google.firebase.crashlytics` like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false

    
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.10' apply false  // Google Services plugin
    // Crashlytics Gradle plugin
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics' version '2.8.1' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: this is the new way

Answer (score 0):

In `<project>/build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
    }
}

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules`.
```

And in `<project>/<app-module>/build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'//this one
}
```

And this in dependencies:

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.2.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
```

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin DSL

```
id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics") version "2.9.5" apply false
```